# How to read an object from app.config?

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

This is not a new question, but I've been researching this for two days and all the answers I can find are outdated or unhelpful. What I want to do is put an object into App.config and then load it when the program starts.

I've got a basic class called "Person" with three autoproperties: (string) FirstName, (string) LastName, and (int) Age. Here's my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/></startup>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="People">
      <section 
        name="Person" 
        type="Person.Person"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <People>
    <Person>
      <Person type="Person.Person, Person">
        <FirstName>Jimmy</FirstName>
        <LastName>Dean</LastName>
        <Age>2</Age>
      </Person>
    </Person>
  </People>
</configuration>
```

And here is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace AppConfigTest
{
    class AppConfigTester
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var guy = (Person.Person) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("People/Person");
            Console.WriteLine(guy.FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine(guy.LastName);
            Console.WriteLine(guy.Age);
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment it crashes with a ConfigurationErrorsException. Any help would be very appreciated. It's boggling my mind that this is so difficult, when App.config is supposed to make doing this sort of thing easier.

Comment: Where do you define your custom configuration section?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: @David Is that what I'm missing? I had one earlier, based on the deprecated ConfigurationSettings, and ended up scrapping it. I'm so confused at this point. I'll try to make a new one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given a Person POCO class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

First you need to create a class that inherits System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement like this:

```
public class PersonElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    public string InnerText { get; private set; }

    protected override void DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, bool serializeCollectionKey)
    {
        InnerText = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    }
}
```

This is needed so you can have config elements like `<FirstName>Jimmy</FirstName>` with inner text.

Next you need a class that inherits System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection like this:

```
public class PersonSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("FirstName")]
    public PersonElement FirstName
    {
        get { return this["FirstName"] as PersonElement; }
        set { this["FirstName"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("LastName")]
    public PersonElement LastName
    {
        get { return this["LastName"] as PersonElement; }
        set { this["LastName"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Age")]
    public PersonElement Age
    {
        get { return this["Age"] as PersonElement; }
        set { this["Age"] = value; }
    }

    public Person CreatePersonFromConfig()
    {
        return new Person()
        {
            FirstName = this.FirstName.InnerText,
            LastName = this.LastName.InnerText,
            Age = Convert.ToInt32(this.Age.InnerText)
        };
    }
}
```

Your app.config should look like this:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="People">
            <section name="Person" type="Example.PersonSection, Example" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <People>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>Jimmy</FirstName>
            <LastName>Dean</LastName>
            <Age>2</Age>
        </Person>
    </People>
</configuration>
```

Finally somewhere in your code do this:

```
PersonSection config = (PersonSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("People/Person");
Person guy = config.CreatePersonFromConfig();
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I had no idea I needed that PersonElement class. This learning curve has been pretty steep for me, so I definitely appreciate the help.

Comment: How to fetch values if we have multiple persons under People, like more than one Person objects. how do we retrieve it from code?  Appreciate Any help

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your implementation, these are:

1. The `<configSections>` element must be the first element in your `App.config` file
2. The configuration section handler (the type that is described in the `type` attribute of the `section` element) must inherit from [ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection(v=vs.110).aspx).
3. Fully qualifying the types that you're referring to

**The `<configSections>` element must be the first element in your `App.config` file**

The `ConfigurationErrorsException` that is being thrown contains the following detail:

> Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element.

This is calling out the fact that you have to move the `<configSections>` element to the top of the file. I guess this is so the code that processes the configuration file can load the appropriate handlers for each section *before* it reads each section of the config file.

**The configuration section handler (the type that is described in the `type` attribute of the `section` element) must inherit from `ConfigurationSection`**

Unfortunately the way the configuration system works means that you can't just drop a [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) in and have it take care of wiring it all up for you. There is a tutorial for [creating a custom configuration section on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Fully qualifying the types that you're referring to**

I'm not sure that this is actually causing an issue for you, but it doesn't hurt to be precise to avoid it causing a problem. The following:

```
<section name="Person" type="Person.Person" />
```

Is potentially ambiguous. Assuming that your project compiles to a DLL/EXE called "MyProjectThatContainsPerson", you should consider changing it to:

```
<section name="Person" type="Person.Person, MyProjectThatContainsPerson" />
```

This makes it clear to the configuration system not only what the name of the type is (`Person.Person`) but also what assembly it should attempt to load it from (`MyProjectThatContainsPerson`).

**An example custom section using a built in Section Handler**

If you wanted to add a configuration section that had a custom name (e.g. "MySection") but otherwise behaved the same as `appSettings`, you could have:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="MySection" 
             type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, system, 
                   Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, 
                   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
</configSections>
<MySection>
    <add key="MySetting" value="MyValue" />
</MySection>
```